# Convert .net decimal type to tsql decimal(3,3)

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have stored procedure which gets decimal(3,3) as param. So, when I'm trying to pass this param like this

```
new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@Wear", SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal, Value = wear.WearValue }
```

I'm getting

> *Error converting data type numeric to decimal.*

This exception appears when I try to pass 1.0 value. 
I need to convert 1.0 **exactly** to `decimal(3,3)`. How can I perform this?

Comment: decimal example = 12.34567;

decimal output = Math.Round(example, 3);

Comment: You can't convert `1.0` to a `decimal(3,3)` since a `decimal(3,3)` has space for 3 digits, 3 of which must appear after the decimal point. By deduction, it cannot accept any digits before the decimal point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum value `decimal(3,3)` will allow is `0.999`, so when you try to insert something larger than that exception will occur. try something like `decimal(4,3)`